# Implementing binary search on an array of Strings

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm having a bit of trouble with this. The input array is based on file input and the size of the array is specified by the first line in the file. The binarySearch method seems to look alright but it doesn't seem to be working would. Anybody be able to help? Thanks.

```
public static int binarySearch(String[] a, String x) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length - 1;
    int mid;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (a[mid].compareTo(x) < 0) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else if (a[mid].compareTo(x) > 0) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the name of your file (including file extension): ");
    String filename = input.next();

    String[] numArray;
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
        int count = in.nextInt();

        numArray = new String[count];

        for (int i = 0; in.hasNextInt() && count != -1 && i < count; i++) {
            numArray[i] = in.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) //printing all the elements
        {
            System.out.println(numArray[i]);
        }

        String searchItem = "The";

        System.out.println("The position of the String is:");
        binarySearch(numArray, searchItem);

    } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("That file was not found. Program terminating...");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the array in sorted order when you call `binarySearch`?

Comment: Yea their sorted. When the elements in the array are printed their all coming out as null for some reason.

Comment: In what way is this not working? What is the expected behavior vs the actual behavior? What have you tried?

Comment: Just curious, is this a homework assignment? `Arrays.sort(numArray); Arrays.binarySearch(numArray, "The");` could replace most of this code.

Answer (score 8):

I have added following example for your further referance.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinaryStringSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String array[] ={"EWRSFSFSFSB","BB","AA","SDFSFJ","WRTG","FF","ERF","FED","TGH"};
        String search = "BB";

        Arrays.sort(array);

        int searchIndex = binarySearch(array,search);

        System.out.println(searchIndex != -1 ? array[searchIndex]+ " - Index is "+searchIndex : "Not found");
    }

    public static int binarySearch(String[] a, String x) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = a.length - 1;
        int mid;

        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;

            if (a[mid].compareTo(x) < 0) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else if (a[mid].compareTo(x) > 0) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else {
                return mid;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will help:

```
 public static void main(String ar[]){

    String str[] = {"account","angel","apple","application","black"};
    String search= "application";
    int length = str.length-1;
    BinarySearchInString findStrin = new BinarySearchInString();
    int i = findStrin.find(str, 0, length, search);
    System.out.println(i);
}

  public int find(String first[], int start, int end, String searchString){
    int mid = start + (end-start)/2;

    if(first[mid].compareTo(searchString)==0){
        return mid;
    }
    if(first[mid].compareTo(searchString)> 0){
        return find(first, start, mid-1, searchString);
    }else if(first[mid].compareTo(searchString)< 0){
        return find(first, mid+1, end, searchString);
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

Comment: [Please include explanation of how your code fixes the bug rather than just lots of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

As spotted by @Mike Rylander you forgot to output the result.

You should use [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) instead of your own implementation.

(As a general rule, JRE libraries are well-tested, well-documented and fast. I googled "java binary search" and this question is well-ranked. I had a try with @Thusitha Indunil's code, which didn't appear to work. I googled harder and found `Arrays.binarySearch`, which worked.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that you forgot to output the results. Try replacing `binarySearch(numArray, searchItem);` with  `System.out.println(binarySearch(numArray, searchItem));`

Answer (score 0):

There are four issues that I can spot in addition to the already mentioned missing print of the result.

1: You have a `String[]` called `numArray` and you are searching for a `String`, `"The"` the name `numArray` is possibly a bit mis-leading.

2: I assume you have some sort of specified input file format where the number of `String` in the file are specified by an `integer` as the first token in the file. This is ok however, as a condition in the for loop that populates the `numArray` there is `in.hasNextInt()`, and the next token is taken out of the `Scanner` using `in.nextLine()`. You should use complementing check/removal methods such as `in.hasNext()` with `in.next()`. Check out the `Scanner` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

3: The `binarySearch(String[], String)` method uses `String.compareTo(String)`. This is determines a lexicographical ordering of this `String` to the parameter `String`. Trying to compare upper case to lower case may not yield what you expect, as `"the".compareTo("The")` will not result in `0`. You should check out the `String` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) for options to either force all of your input to one case, maybe while reading the file, or use a different flavor of a compare to method.

4: The last thing that I see may be considered a bit of a corner case, however with a sufficiently large `String` array, and a search string that may reside far in the right side, ie. high index side, of the array you may get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is because `(low + high)` can result in a negative value, when the result "should" be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Then the result is divided by two and still yields a negative value. This can be solved by bit shifting the result instead of dividing by 2, `(low + high) >>> 1`. Joshua Bloch has a great [article](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) about this common flaw in divide and conquer algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int low = fromIndex;
    int high = toIndex - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;

        Comparable midVal = (Comparable) a[mid];

        int cmp = midVal.compareTo(key);

        if (cmp < 0)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (cmp > 0)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return -(low + 1);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to explain your answer, not simply paste code.